# iOS device not showing icon while simulator can show

Tags: ios, icons

I'm using assets catalogs. After run the app, I can see the icon in simulator, while I can't see it on actual device. I think there should be no difference. I tried delete, clean the project and reboot the device. No luck. And this only happens to one of my app, another app can show properly on both device and simulator.

UPDATE:
I found this may because the source file of icon. I tried to use another icon which can show on device and it works. But still don't understand why it can show on simulator while can not show on device

Answer (score 0):

Try and compare the icon that does work, and the icon that doesn't work.

You can compare things like:

- File extension
- Resolution
- Size
- Color
- Bit Depth
- ...

If you see a difference between them, change the one that doesn't work to match the one that does work.

As you provided very little information I'm not sure if this will work, but it's worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Levi's answer also make sure the file naming casing is correct. The simulator is not case sensitive but an actual device filesystem is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Copy File Window]

Sometimes image file are not copied properly.
**Try below approach:**

Delete image from xcode and re-check in your folder location that its deleted.

Copy image file to your project.
Check options as per the image and test it again on simulator and on device.

And also perform checks mentioned in other answers.